# four square api doesn't work properly

Tags: foursquare

I am using four square API to display the auto suggestions when user types a word. I use:

```
$http.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?&near='+input+'&query=' +input+'&intent=gloabal&limit=5&oauth_token=D5STL1YLFPPGLOF121W....&v=2016...')
```

But I am not getting the exact results. Sometimes it shows nothing giving empty objects and also in different languages like tamil, urdu, etc...

Then I tried with an example - taj mahal. If I type taj,taj ma, taj maha like that... It doesn't show anything... API suggests taj mahal only when i type taj mahal fully in the search box.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to debug this for you. Here are some glaring things that might be the issue here:

a) It appears that your intent specifies `gloabal` vs `global`, which would likely default to the intent `checkin` via https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

b) Could be an issue with your search e.g. searching for the taj mahal near the taj mahal.

To get into the details more, it might help to dig into some of the raw HTTP requests being sent to Foursquare.

Here is a sample CURL command for finding 'food' near the Taj Mahal.

```
curl -v 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?&near=taj%20mahal&query=food&intent=global&limit=5&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20160828'
```

To diagnose the issue, it might make sense to try and simulate both inputs e.g. near and query params using curl above to diagnose whether the response is what you are looking for.

In addition it's worthwhile noting that `near` must be a string representing a place in the world. If the near string is not `geocodable` you should see a `failed_geocode` error. Specific to your question if you use the the param `near=taj%20ma` you'll likely get a `failed_geocode` probably as expected. More details via https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

For specifics on language, my understanding is that you can set the locale in the Accept-Language HTTP header in your request (preferred) or alternatively specify parameter `locale`. If nothing is specified my assumption is that the language that's most popular in the country for that venue will likely be used. More details via https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning